# How to read XML and show the data on label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drivers>

<driver>
<img><![CDATA[45djx96.jpg]]></img>
<name><![CDATA[Alonso]]></name>
<teamname><![CDATA[farari]]></teamname>
<ref><![CDATA[45djx96]]></ref>
</driver>

<driver>
<img><![CDATA[1236.jpg]]></img>
<name><![CDATA[Alonso2]]></name>
<teamname><![CDATA[farari2]]></teamname>
<ref><![CDATA[1236]]></ref>
</driver>

<driver>
<img><![CDATA[1245FGt.jpg]]></img>
<name><![CDATA[Alonso3]]></name>
<teamname><![CDATA[farari3]]></teamname>
<ref><![CDATA[1245FGt]]></ref>
</driver>

</drivers>
```

I want to show the only  details

means 1236,s  name & teamname on UILable.

I am using webservice frist time. I succeed to catch XML on Console but cant able to read XML and show the value of name & team name on UILable.

now xml is showing on console but cant able to parse.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `TouchXML` you can parse this data in to array and also single record to string i just post some code about it

```
CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
NSArray *nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//driver" error:nil];

for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {      
    // Create Object Of Bean Class. if required

    for(int counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {          
        //Save Data in The Bean Class and Add In the Array.

        if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"teamname"]) {                 
            NSString *string = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
                            yourLable.Text = string;
            //                NSLog(@"\n\n Title %@",string);

        }
        else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"ref"]) {                 
            NSString *string = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
           //                NSLog(@"\n\n Ref %@",string);
        } 
}
```

}

**for TouchXML see this Tutorial and Example Also**

1. [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML)
2. [iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks for replying but its not working for me. It says unknown receiver "CXMLDocument"

Comment: @AreebaKhan yes mate first download the touchXML library and put in your project and import header file like #import "CXMLDocument.h" then its work and for more detail see the link tutorial and the try with Demo mate.. :)

Answer (score 1):

For parsing you can use TBXML which required following classes.
TBXML.h,TBXML.m & NSDataAdditions.h,NSDataAdditions.m.

I have given one sample example.You can do changes according to your code

```
 NSString *cStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><SetPatientBPXMLResponse xmlns=\"http://webservice.cruxmed.com/\"><SetPatientBPXMLResult><response><state><![CDATA[45djx96.jpg]]></state></response></SetPatientBPXMLResult></SetPatientBPXMLResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];

    TBXML *tbxmlObj = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:cStr];

    // Obtain root element
    TBXMLElement * root = tbxmlObj.rootXMLElement;
    //-------------------------------------------
    if (root)
    {
        //-------------------------------------------
        // search for the first NewDataSet element within the root element's children
        // instantiate an NewDataSet objectGetDataInXMLFromStoredProcedureResponse
        TBXMLElement * SoapBody = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"soap:Body" parentElement:root];

        TBXMLElement * SoapResponse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"SetPatientBPXMLResponse" parentElement:SoapBody];

        TBXMLElement * SoapResult = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"SetPatientBPXMLResult" parentElement:SoapResponse];

        //TBXMLElement * NewDataSet1 = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"response" parentElement:SoapResult];

        TBXMLElement * NewDataSet = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"response" parentElement:SoapResult];
        // if an _wspGetChartTemplateByAgent element was found
        while (NewDataSet != nil) {


            //cAccountName,fOrdTotTaxDEx,fOrdTotTax,;

            // instantiate a Order object


            // find the iInvoiceId
            TBXMLElement * AutoIndex = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"state" parentElement:NewDataSet];

            if (AutoIndex != nil)
            {
                NSString* iVal=[TBXML textForElement:AutoIndex] ;
                NSLog(@"iVal:%@",iVal);
            }
            // find the next sibling element named "_wspGetChartTemplateByAgent"
            NewDataSet = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"response" searchFromElement:NewDataSet];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, NSXMLParser class should ring the bell I think.
However, it is not so handy, you can find many better parsers, for example TBXML ([one of branches](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)).
In additions, it is commonly advised to use JSON instead of XML since it is lighter and easier to parse. Most common JSON parser library is SBJSON.